# How do I add parameters to a data pipeline in Foundry?

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, data-pipeline

I have a PySpark data pipeline that I want to parameterize in Foundry. How can I get Foundry to read a “configuration file” when running the pipeline?

I want the pipeline to be flexible and parameterizable, but if I define the parameters in the code, I will need to commit every change to those parameters into the repository.

Answer (score 3):

To add parameters to a data pipeline, start by defining your parameters in a dataset. You can use Fusion for this. A straightforward schema involves creating one column per parameter, and giving your table a single row.
You can learn about how to create Tables in Fusion spreadsheets [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/fusion/create-use-table-regions/) (public documentation), and how to synchronize those to a dataset [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/fusion/sync-table-dataset/) (public documentation).
Once you have your dataset, create `config.py` in your code repository like so:

```
from typing import Any as _Any
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame as _df


class Config(object):
    def __init__(
        self,
        string_param: str,
        string_param_with_default: str,
        list_param: list(),
        int_param: int,
        **kwargs: _Any,
    ) -> None:
        self.string_param= string_param
        self.string_param_with_default= string_param_with_default or "foo"
        self.list_param = list_param or []
        self.int_param = int_param or 1


def config_from_dataset(config_df: _df) -> Config:
    return Config(**config_df.collect()[0].asDict())
```

After that you can call your configuration like so:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T
from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output, Check
from transforms import expectations as E
from myproject.config import config_from_dataset



@transform_df(
    Output("path/to/output"),
    source_df=Input("path/to/input"),
    config=Input(
        "path/to/config",
        checks=[
            Check(E.count().equals(1), "Config should have exactly 1 row"),
            Check(
                E.schema().equals({
                    'string_param': T.StringType(),
                    'string_param_with_default': T.StringType(),
                    'list_param': T.ArrayType(T.StringType()),
                    'int_param': T.IntegerType(),
                }),
                "Config should have fixed schema"
            )
        ]
    )
)
def compute(source_df, config):
    config = config_from_dataset(config)
    # grab a parameter
    string_param = config.string_param 
    # use the param
    return source_df.filter(F.col("name").eqNullSafe(string_param))
```

In the code snippet above I’ve included a Check on the input that validates the configuration table.